# not waiting for data to be fetched from server on http get request angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, es6-promise

hi i have local server on port A and single web app on port 4200
server has some data i request via http

data.service.ts:

```
    export class DataService {
      constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

      async get_p() {
        return await this.httpClient.get<object[]>('/some api').toPromise();
      }

      async get_s() {
        return await this.httpClient.get<object[]>('/some api').toPromise();
      }
    }
```

in another ts file :

```
          init() {
            let p1 =this.dataService.get_s().then((result) => {this.s = 
             result; } ) ;
            let p2 = this.dataService.get_p().then((result) => {this.p = 
             result; } );

            Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(values => {
              console.log(values); ///undefined
            });

            console.log("not waiting for data");
```

well ther are error messages but they refer to the fact that both p and s are not intialized.

i have already checked that data comes ok from server by doing this requests in constructor and then i moved them to init function.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `p1` and `p2` promises don't have any resolved value because the `.then()` handlers assign `result` to `this.s` and `this.p`, but they don't return anything, therefore the resolved values for `p1` and `p2` are `undefined`.  Remember, the return value from a `.then()` handler becomes the resolved value of the promise.

Thus, when you do this:

```
Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(values => {
    console.log(values); ///undefined
});
```

All `values` will be is an array of `undefined`.  If instead, you do this:

```
Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(values => {
    console.log(this.p, this.s);
});
```

you should see your values.  Or, alternatively you can actually return those values from the `.then()` handlers and then each promise will have a resolved value.

```
      init() {
        let p1 =this.dataService.get_s().then((result) => {
            this.s = result; 
            return result;  // set resolved value of promise
        });
        let p2 = this.dataService.get_p().then((result) => {
             this.p = result; 
             return result;  // set resolved value of promise
        });

        Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(values => {
          console.log(values); // will show the resolved values now
        });
```

Comment: Could you please help me here @jfriend

Comment: @Profer - Help with what?